# I have Netbeans 8.1 it only supports C/C++ and does support java.

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have Netbeans 8.1 it only supports C/C++ and does support java. I need Netbeans 8.1 to support Java projects. What do I have to do to get Netbeans to support java development?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Plugins -> Installed tab. Then locate and select `Java SE` and Click Activate button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Download Install a Java JDK 8 (or whatever Java JDK) and then register it within the NetBeans IDE.

1) In the IDE, choose Tools > Java Platforms from the main menu.

2) Click Add Platform in the Java Platform Manager dialog.

3) In the Add Java Platform dialog, select Java Standard Edition and click Next.

4) Specify the directory that contains the JDK and click Next.

Read this [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8.html).